# how to remove a box2d Fixture

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

I have a square barrier that has edges defined at run time based on where the user puts the position and rotation of my barrier.

```
b2BodyDef barrierBodyDef;
barrierBodyDef.type = b2_staticBody;
barrierBodyDef.position.Set(curBarrier
                            .position.x/PTM_RATIO, curBarrier.position.y/PTM_RATIO);
barrierBodyDef.userData = curBarrier;


b2Body *barrierBody;
barrierBody = _world->CreateBody(&barrierBodyDef);

b2EdgeShape barrierEdge;
b2FixtureDef barrierShapeDef;
barrierShapeDef.shape = &barrierEdge;
barrierShapeDef.friction = 1.0f;

barrierEdge.Set(b2Vec2((x1)/PTM_RATIO, (y1)/PTM_RATIO),
                b2Vec2((x2)/PTM_RATIO, (y2)/PTM_RATIO));
barrierBody->CreateFixture(&barrierShapeDef);
barrierEdge.Set(b2Vec2((x2)/PTM_RATIO, (y2)/PTM_RATIO),
                b2Vec2((x3)/PTM_RATIO, (y3)/PTM_RATIO));
barrierBody->CreateFixture(&barrierShapeDef);
barrierEdge.Set(b2Vec2((x3)/PTM_RATIO, (y3)/PTM_RATIO),
                b2Vec2((x4)/PTM_RATIO, (y4)/PTM_RATIO));
barrierBody->CreateFixture(&barrierShapeDef);
barrierEdge.Set(b2Vec2((x4)/PTM_RATIO, (y4)/PTM_RATIO),
                b2Vec2((x1)/PTM_RATIO, (y1)/PTM_RATIO));
barrierBody->CreateFixture(&barrierShapeDef);
```

I now want to delete these edges, so that the user can re-position the barrier.

How do I go about removing the edges between point x1,y1, -> x4,y4, so that they are immune to collisions.

I am a bit new to Box2D.

Comment: Right so: 

_world->DestroyBody(barrierBody);

Then recreate a new body with the new position?

Comment: Yes recreate with new positions..

Comment: @Guru: of course you can remove fixtures, but you can not remove a fixture's shape nor change the shape's … err, shape. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Keep the fixture when creating it (local var here for example, you should use an ivar):

```
b2Fixture* barrierFixture = barrierBody->CreateFixture(&barrierShapeDef);
```

And later destroy the fixture:

```
barrierBody->DestroyFixture(barrierFixture);
barrierFixture = nil;
```

You can also use the body's `GetFixtureList()` to iterate over fixtures.

What you can not do is to add or remove shapes from a fixture, or modify the shape's vertices. To remove a point from a body's shape, you'll have to destroy the fixture and replace it with a new one.

It is not necessary to recreate the entire body, in fact that can be problematic since you'll probably want to preserve the body's current state (not just position but also linear and angular velocities and perhaps other things too).